# UITextField should accept only english letters, numbers and special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, uitextview, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to restrict textview character only to english. But if I copy and paste non english character my textview takes those entries. Can anyone help me solving this issue. UITextView should only takes english characters(including special characters, number and space too). Or when I clicks on done It should validate and throw me a error message if the textview contains non english characters.

Thanks in advance.

Below are my code

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        if(textField == yourTextField)
        {
            NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"] invertedSet] invertedSet];
            NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
        }
        else
            return YES;
    }
```

This code does not allow me to enter space and special character. Need a help to solve this.

Comment: Show the code you currently have.

Comment: @Wain edited my question. Please go through the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'string' contains the **typed character**. why are you comparing it to a **long string** of all the allowed characters? it will never be equal. Also, why are you inverting the allowed set **twice**?

Answer (score 0):

// i hope it will work for you

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField == yourTextField)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *s = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_!@#$%^&*()-+="];
       s = [s invertedSet];
      NSRange r = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:s];
    if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
 // alert code here
  return NO;

} else {
   return YES;
}

    }
    else
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried above code but its not at all taking any character and isValid bool value is always return <nil>, If u dont mind can u please put it in  -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text Method

Comment: I tried this code before. This code wont take special characters :(

Comment: Above code wont take all the special character and space. I have tried this too :(

Comment: addthose charecters in above mentioned string

Comment: append charecters to this string [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_!@#$%^&*()-+="];

Answer (score 0):

I guess (haven't tried) you can `getCharacters:` of `string` and iterate them, then call `characterIsMember:` on your allowed character set to verify each one. If any fail then you return `NO`.